# How to deploy new version of Web-App without owner privileges?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

1. Once we create a new version and deployment ID, what do we need to do to make that version live? Do we need to publish it via the Publish -> Deploy as web add-on? and then it will be live?
2. It seems only the owner of the Project can do Publish -> Deploy as web add-on. This creates a single point of failure/bottleneck where multiple people might work on the project. What do you suggest we do to avoid this?

Comment: Try team drives. If your all full managers on the team drive then you can all remove copies of the scripts and run them as you own.  If you try to deploy them on the team drives you'll find that only the original owner can do that.

Comment: In answer to your second question use a team drive where all members have full access.